# CSS <select> dropdown not displaying background color in iOS/iPAD browsers

Tags: html, ios, css, dropdown

I have a  dropdown box and styled it with CSS; background color is red and border is yellow. This displays fine in all PC browsers, but in iOS/iPAD browser the background remains grey (standard color I guess).

Here is my CSS:

```
select#json-one{
    width:15%;
    margin:10px 10px;
    padding:6px 6px;
    border:#FF0 1px solid;
    background-color:#7f3133;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

and here is my HTML:

```
<form action="" method="get" id="form1">
    <select id="json-one">
        <option selected value="norway">Norway</option>
        <option value="usa">USA</option>
        <option value="denmark">Denmark</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Is there a way to fix this in the CSS code, or do I need to use JavaScript / JQuery? I cannot successfully find out how to style  dropdowns using JavaScript, so help on this would be much appreciated.

To illustrate my problem, please see screenshots here:
http://jazzkatt.net/testtwo/

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/ hope this helps. i just tested its in my mac it's working fine to me. let me know if you need any more help

Answer (score 4):

You can't change the appearance of selectbox items in iOS browsers. iOS Safari doesn't apply to the style you give it. You would have to make your dropdowns in pure javascript to give them a different style

Comment: Thank you for the information. Would you happen to have a link to a tutorial for creating dropdowns in pure javascript?

Comment: I agree with Sastry. It's indeed almost impossible to change the appearance of selectboxes in WKWebView or Safari. The popover view that you see after tapping on your select box is a native controller of private type WKSelectTableViewController. It presents a tableview but with cells containing also private UITableViewCellContentViews... You cannot change its properties. Neither in css nor natively. So, implementing your own js based select box is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply style a pseudo element for the background. Just make sure your `::before` matches the style of the select, so include any border-radius, etc.

```css
select#json-one {
  position: relative;
  width: 15%;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  padding: 6px 6px;
  border: #ff0 1px solid;
  background-color: #7f3133;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

select#json-one::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  background-color: #7f3133;
}
```